# What happens as wavelengths of sound waves approach tens of micrometers?

Tags: acoustics

I was having [an online conversation about *Dungeons and Dragons*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/conversation/bb17), and my acquaintance abbreviated "Barbarian Level 17" as Bb17. I took the opportunity to make a joke about how that is similar to musical notation (i.e. B♭₁₇). Then I tried calculating the frequency and wavelength and got:

$$f=3.8 \text{  }GHz$$
$$λ=87.5 \text{  }μm$$

Can a compression wave (not sure you could even call it sound at that point) have such a high frequency? Does anything happen when it does?

Answer (score 5):

When we think of air as a continuous medium that can support waves, we have to assume that the scale of spatial variation in macroscopic quantities (like pressure, density, etc.) is significantly higher than the [mean free path](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/menfre.html) of the molecules.   To within an order of magnitude, the mean free path of air molecules is around 0.1 µm, which is still a few orders of magnitude smaller than the wavelengths you're looking at.  So treating this as a sound wave is probably still fine.

It's also worth noting that [acoustic microscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_microscopy) uses sound waves with frequencies up to a few GHz, not too far off from what you're talking about.  However, we're usually talking about waves in solids or liquids in this case;  in air, waves of high frequencies like this are quickly attenuated as they propagate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, no problem in principle.

The limit for wavelengths is the interatomic distance. The cut-off frequencies for phonons in solids are about $10^{13}$ Hz.

In gases, attenuation goes up a lot a short wavelengths. This paper says that attenuation in air is 80 000 dB/m (for $f = 20$  MHz): http://acoustics.ippt.pan.pl/index.php/aa/article/viewFile/555/486